# How to make paragraph fit different browser width

Tags: html, css, frontend, blogs, paragraph

I am in the process of building up a `html` and `CSS` template for my personal blog posts. The portion of my blog content is as follow:

```css
.content {
  text-align: center;
  width: 60%;
}

.blog_content {
  background-color: white;
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<section class="content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="blog_content">
      <h2>This is the post title!</h2>
      <h3>Title description!</h3>
      <div class="photo">
        <img src="#" alt="NULL">
      </div>
      <p>
        This is the first paragraph!
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I wanted to make paragraphs always 60% of the browser width and always remain centered. However, my `CSS` code did not work-I tried putting text-align: center and width: 60% in every container in my content section, but nothing worked.

Any assistance greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are duplicating your width declaration. You need only to declare the content width as 100% and then declare its paragraphs as 60%:

```
.content {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.content > p {
  background-color: white;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:block;
}
```

Alternately, and preferably, you may give your paragraph tags a class and target them directly within your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

In your code by adding `margin: auto;` to `.blog-content` and removing width given to `.content` will solve your problem.

```css
.content {
  text-align: center;
}

.blog_content {
  background-color: white;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="blog_content">
      <h2>This is the post title!</h2>
      <h3>Title description!</h3>
      <div class="photo">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x30" alt="NULL">
      </div>
      <p>
        This is the first paragraph!
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.blog_content {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;  // 60 -> 100
}
```

`.blog_content` is relative to `.content`.